# Aerospike synchronous get method for node.js client

Tags: node.js, aerospike

Is there any synchronous database read and write method in Aerospike for Node.js client?

Comment: Wouldn't that be against the philosophy of node.js?

Comment: I totally agree with you, I would hate to be the one who uses sync ops in node.js environment. But the time I asked the question I had a practical problem, I'm building a caching system which requires a bunch of database connections. I designed the cache in a sync manner so that once the cache is fully deployed then the http server could listen, but as I was dealing with async database read theoretically my server could start listening even before the cache is fully deployed. So I was looking for a synchronous approch. I think I was lazy but thanks to "necessity" I made the cache async :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the API calls in the Aerospike client client use an async. pattern to connect, read data etc, this is to be expected in Node.js.

You can use the new (since Node 7.6) async/await keywords to allow code to be written in a more readable way though. It is not synchronous (since testRead does not block) but it reads much more like synchronous code.

```
const Aerospike = require('aerospike')
var batchRecords = [
  { key: new Aerospike.Key('test', 'demo', 'key1'), bins: ['i', 's'] },
  { key: new Aerospike.Key('test', 'demo', 'key2'), read_all_bins: true },
  { key: new Aerospike.Key('test', 'demo', 'key3') }
];

async function testRead()
{
    var result = await readFromAerospike(batchRecords);
    console.log(result);
}

function readFromAerospike(batchRecords) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       Aerospike.connect((err, client) => {
          if (err) {
              reject(err);
          } else {
              client.batchRead(batchRecords, (err, results) => {
                  if (err) {
                      reject(err);
                  } else {
                      resolve(results);
                  }
              })
          }
       });
   });
}

testRead();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for sharing. I wish there's a sync pattern too.

Comment: Since v3.0, the Aerospike Node.js client supports promises and async/await, so you could also just write `let client = await Aerospike.connect(); let result = await client.batchRead(batchReads)`, etc. I think that gets pretty close to the synchronous pattern you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, _Jan Hecking_ I was aware of that and I actually needed those db ops even before my server starts listening, so sync approach was much more practical for me because of managing all those twisted nesting loops and callbacks I have been working on. But I made it async anyway :)

Comment: OMG The _Jan Hecking_!!! :) I look up for your comments in aerospike discussion forum all the time, I love the way you approach problems and provide solutions for them, Well speaking of the problem- is there any way in aerospike to listen for a particular record changes/modifications via key?